# A problem on distribution functions

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a quick question here. From the definition of a distribution function (DF),

$\text{A real-valued, nondecreasing, right continuous function} \; F \; \text{defined on} \;\left(-\infty,\infty\right)\;\text{satisfying}$$$ F(-\infty)=0 \; \text{and} \; F(\infty)=1 $$ $\text{is called a DF}.$

I encountered this problem.

$\text{Consider the function}$ $$F(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan{x} \;,\;-\infty<x<\infty$$
$\text{Is this a DF?}$

Now, from what I understood, although it satisfies the conditions of (1) being nondecreasing, (2) right continuous, and (3) real-valued, I found that 
$$F(-\infty)=-\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$F(\infty)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Clearly, from my solution, it must not be a DF. However, the answer from another reference which I studied said it is a DF, with a PDF of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}I^{(x)}_{(-\infty,\infty)}$$
Now, I know that $f(x)$ can be verified to be a PDF since $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$ and its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$. So now, I am in the dilemma of what should my answer to the problem is, i.e. is $F$ a DF or not?

Please help. In case it is, please explain where was I wrong in the $F(-\infty) \; \text{and} \; F(\infty)$ conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $F$ will be a distribution function after adding the adequate constant, namely, $\frac 12$. So $F$ as written in the OP is *not* a DF, but $F+1/2$ is a DF.

Comment: So it would appear as if a "jump" would exist, doesn't it? However, my problem is that if I will rely on PDF, the answer would be that it is a DF, but it I rely on the definition given, it would appear that it is not a DF. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by jump here? (everything is continuous)

Comment: Ok I was wrong with the jump part. Sorry. Ah,so ok, I think that solves my problem. Although, I think what you meant is $F+1/2$, instead of $F-1/2$. Thanks :)

Comment: Fixed now. you are welcome.